# how can I code a tab feature in command line?

Tags: python

I am trying to build this feature in python when I type `shell> listeners` then it will be changed to `shell>listeners>` , but I dont know how or where to start doing this. I have tried this, but I want to output like this `shell (hello)(aa)(aaa) >>`

```
sections = ["shell"]

def render_sections():
    return ">".join([*sections, ''])

def get_command():
    return input(render_sections()).strip()

while 1:
    command = get_command()
    if command == 'exit':
        break
    elif command == '':
        continue
    else:
        sections.append(command)
```

Comment: Please share code which you have tried till now.

Comment: sure, I have updated the question . , but I am trying to achieve `shell (aa)(aa)(aa) >>` depends on if I `shell > aa` which it will be translated to `shell (aa) >>` so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want something like this:

```
def render_sections():
    first, rest = sections[:1], sections[1:]
    return ' '.join(first + [''.join(['(%s)' % s for s in rest])] + [">>"])
```

Which produces:

```
shell  >>hello
shell (hello) >>aa
shell (hello)(aa) >>aaa
shell (hello)(aa)(aaa) >>
```